# Rails routing error when getting rid of prefix in the URL path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my routes file i have

```
  resources :contractors, :path => '/' 
  resources :customers, :path => '/'
```

Note: Both have their own registration/devise models.

Now the thing is, if the `contractor` logs in. He is able to browse around fine. But when the `customer` logs in it says `Couldn't find Contractr with id=1` . Now if I reverse the order

```
    resources :customers, :path => '/'
  resources :contractors, :path => '/'
```

It works fine for customer and not for the contractor. I think I know what the problem here is. But how do I solve it? I dont know want `/customers/` or `/contractors/` as a prefix in the URLs

Comment: What login system are you using? Devise?

Comment: Yes, I am using devise.

Answer (score 0):

You should scope if you want to have the same path to 2 different resources:

```
devise_scope(:contractor) { resources :contractors, path: '/' }
devise_scope(:customer)   { resources :customers,   path: '/' }
```